# having VS outer query

Tags: mysql, sql

Please take a look at these two queries:

**One:**

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_time)
    SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
    FROM (select count(*) as num_month,
                 count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day))) as num_day,
                 count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 minute))) as num_90min
          from QANDA  
          where author_id = :id and
               type = 0 and
               date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 50 day))
         ) a 
    WHERE num_month < 50 and num_day < 6 and num_90min < 1;
```

**Two:**

```
INSERT INTO QandA (id, body, type, related, author_id, date_time)
SELECT NULL, :body, 0, NULL, :id, unix_timestamp
FROM dual
WHERE user_id = :id 
   AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT count(*) AS num_month
               count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 1 day))) as num_day,
               count(date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 90 minute))) as num_90min
        FROM QandA
        WHERE author_id = :id and
              type = 0 and
              date_time > unix_timestamp(DATE_SUB(now(), INTERVAL 50 day))
        HAVING num_90min  > 50 
            OR num_day    > 6 
            OR num_month  > 1 
    )
```

As you see both of them areidentical, just first one uses an *outer query* and second one uses *`having`* clause. Well which approach is better? Or is there any third approach which is bettern than them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is standard SQL, so you should understand it.

The second is an extension of the `having` clause in MySQL.  Normally, the `having` clause would only be used in an aggregation query -- you would see aggregation functions somewhere in the query.  In MySQL (and several other databases), `having` allows the use of column aliases, whereas the `WHERE` clause does not.

Let's add one more important consideration.  In general, MySQL *materializes* subqueries.  That means that a subquery will incur extra overhead to write out the data and read it back in.  Most other databases have better optimizers and don't materialize all/most subqueries in the `FROM` clause.

So, to be more efficient, MySQL allows you to use the `HAVING` clause in a non-aggregation query.  In this case, it functions just like a `WHERE` clause, except you can reference column aliases.

Conclusion:  The first is better because it is more standard SQL.  The second is better because it should run faster.  All depends on what you mean by "better".